# How is $L^* - \{\epsilon \} \neq L^+$?

Tags: formal-languages, kleene-star

I was asked which among the following is true:

> 1. $\Sigma^*-\{\epsilon\} = \Sigma^+$
> 2. $L^* - \{\epsilon \} = L^+$

As I can see, both $\Sigma^*$ & $L^*$ are sets. I thought both were true because of set difference, but the answer lists only the first option as correct and the second as false. How so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\varepsilon \in L$, then necessarily $\varepsilon \in L^+$ (and the converse as well). This is because $L$ itself is contained in $L^+$ and $L^+$ is defined as the union over the powers $L^i$ of $L$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}_+$. Note $L^+$ is *not* defined as $L^\ast \setminus \{ \varepsilon \}$; this is a common mistake.

Hence, $\varepsilon \not\in L^+$ holds if and only if $\varepsilon \not\in L$. This is the case for the alphabet $\Sigma$, hence why it is correct in the first case.

Comment: Can't $\sum = \{\epsilon\}$ or $\epsilon \in \sum$?

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. Well, it depends on what $\Sigma$ is. Usually it is meant as an alphabet, so defining it like that would mean $\varepsilon$ is a symbol; I have no clue how you would separate that from the *empty word* $\varepsilon$ (though I could imagine Machiavellian examiners abusing such things). If $\Sigma$ is meant as a language, then, sure, $\Sigma = \{ \varepsilon \}$ is possible (and not ambiguous). Note $\Sigma$ cannot be just a "set" since it must contain words; otherwise, the definition for $\Sigma^+$ simply does not work because $\Sigma^i$ is undefined (regarding concatenation).

Comment: oh, so should I assume null is not to be taken as an alphabet unless mentioned?

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. With "null" you mean the empty word $\varepsilon$? As I have said, I cannot imagine using $\varepsilon$ being used as a symbol except in the (very) restricted case of formulating trick questions. At any rate, $\Sigma$ should be given explicitly; if this is not the case, then $\varepsilon$ can safely be assumed not to be an element of it (since *words* should **not** be elements of *alphabets*, which are sets of *symbols*).

Comment: I am not sure the problem is well defined. What if $L = \Sigma$ ? Is it true 1 and 2 are the same in this case?

Comment: 2. really doesn't have a yes/no answer because $L$ isn't specified, but what probably is meant there is whether $\forall L: L^* - \{\epsilon \} = L^+$, in which case the answer is no, as dkaeae explains.